# How to configure "end to end" publisher confirms with Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I want to use publisher confirms with RabbitMQ and Spring AMQP such that the message confirm callback gets a NACK if the listener throws an exception during processing the message.

Following [this blog post](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/), I am talking about the use case marked in red:

[image]

Main question is:

1. how do I have to configure the ConnectionFactory, RabbitTemplate and ListenerContainer to enable manual NACKs?
2. what do I have to do in my listener in order to NACK the message and call the confirm callback with `success = false` in case of an exception?

Here are my beans:

```or-tag-here
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ConfirmCallback confirmCallback() {
    return new ConfirmCallbackTestImplementation();
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ConfirmCallback confirmCallback) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(confirmCallback);
    rabbitTemplate.setExchange(DIRECT_EXCHANGE);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public FaultyMessageListener faultyListener(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin, DirectExchange exchange, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    Queue queue = queue(rabbitAdmin, exchange, "faultyListener");
    FaultyMessageListener listener = new FaultyMessageListener();
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    container.setMessageListener(listener);
    container.setQueues(queue);
    container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    container.start();
    return listener;
}

private Queue queue(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin, DirectExchange exchange, String routingKey) {
    Queue queue = new Queue(routingKey, true, false, true);
    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey));
    return queue;
}
```

Here is my Listener implementation:

```or-tag-here
public class FaultyMessageListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

    private final List<Message> receivedMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        receivedMessages.add(message);
        channel.basicNack(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false, false);
        latch.countDown();
        throw new AmqpException("Message could not be processed");
    }

}
```

Here is my confirmation callback:

```or-tag-here
public static class ConfirmCallbackTestImplementation implements ConfirmCallback {

    private volatile Map<String, Boolean> confirmations = new HashMap<>();
    private volatile HashMap<String, CountDownLatch> expectationLatches = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean success, String s) {
        confirmations.put(correlationData.getId(), success);
        expectationLatches.get(correlationData.getId()).countDown();
    }

    public CountDownLatch expect(String correlationId) {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        this.expectationLatches.put(correlationId, latch);
        return latch;
    }

}
```

I then use the following test to verify the desired behavior:

```or-tag-here
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate template;

@Autowired
private FaultyMessageListener faultyListener;

@Autowired
private ConfirmCallbackTestImplementation testConfirmCallback;

@Test
public void sendMessageToFaultyMessageListenerResultsInNack() throws InterruptedException {
    String correlationId = "corr-data-test-2";
    CountDownLatch confirmationLatch = testConfirmCallback.expect(correlationId);

    template.convertAndSend("ConnectionsTests.PublisherConfirm", "faultyListener", "faulty message", new CorrelationData(correlationId));

    assertTrue(faultyListener.latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    confirmationLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    assertThat(faultyListener.receivedMessages.size(), is(1));
    assertThat(testConfirmCallback.confirmations.get(correlationId), is(false));
}
```

The result of the test is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
    Expected: is <false>
         but: was <true>
```

for the last assertion. For me, this reads like the confirm callback is always called with `success = true` instead of `success = false` what I'd expect from the `channel.basicNack(...)` in my listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work that way; the ack/nack on the publisher side is purely whether the broker has accepted the message. In fact, a nack is rarely returned since it means a problem in the broker itself - see [the rabbit documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).

> basic.nack will only be delivered if an internal error occurs in the Erlang process responsible for a queue.

Similarly the ack/nack on the consumer side is purely about whether the consumer has accepted responsibility for the message and the nack allows the message to be requeued, discarded, or routed to a dead-letter queue.

Once the message is published, there is no communication back to the publisher from the consumer(s). If you need such communication, you need to set up reply queues.

You can use [Spring Remoting (RPC) Over RabbitMQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#remoting) instead if you want tight coupling between the publisher and consumer. If the consumer throws an exception, it will be propagated back to the publisher - however, that mechanism only supports Java `Serializable` objects.

Although the documentation references XML, you can wire up the proxy and service invoker as `@Bean`s